# Javascript in html tags to avoid repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie to JavaScript and I need to use it with bootstrap for my own web page. My question is now how can I make a loop so that pictures names (stored as an array) can emerge in the right places of the HTML code so I do not have to  copy the blocks of code for each picture.

For example :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="01.jpg">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="01.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="02.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="03.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

As we can see here the only different text is the src.How can I store the names (paths) in an array and make a loop that changes the src property? 
Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript templates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating & https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this demo: http://jsbin.com/pinoxeqapi/1/edit?html,output

I think that's what you're looking for.

## CODE

```
$(function () {
   var images = ["01.jpg", "01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg"];
   
   $.each(images, function (index, element) {
     var imgContainer = "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item><img class='img-responsive' src='" + element + "'></div></div>";
      $("body").append(imgContainer);
   });
});
```

Comment: Post code in answer itself. Simply posting a link ***is not*** an answer. Answers should be self contained and links should only used to support what is in the answer itself. In short...this is nothing but a comment

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: how can I call the function ? I just pasted it in my HTML-code  using <script> </script> but it seems not to be working (pictures are not being showed).

Answer (score 1):

First Include [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) (If not)

```
<script>
var srcArray = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg'];

$(document).ready(function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
        $('div.row img.img-responsive').eq(i).attr("src", srcArray[i]);
     }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template stored in the HTML and then generate the actual elements using an array of the image sources. Something like [John Resig's micro-templates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) can achieve this.

```
<script type="text/template" id="img-tmpl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= src %>">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of the templating frameworks described in some of the other answers. If you're interested to see how to implement this in pure JS:

```js
var temp = document.querySelector('#portfolio-item-template');
['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg'].forEach(function(src) {
  temp.content.querySelector(".img-responsive").src = src;
  var newImg = document.importNode(temp.content, true);
  document.querySelector('#insertion-point').appendChild(newImg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="portfolio-item-template">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
      <img class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="insertion-point">
</div>
```